# Using a Subclass vs Using an Identifying Field or Static Constant

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm actually looking for a general answer or link to info on the subject, but I think the question is best illustrated by a specific example:

Ex. 1:

```
class Car {

}

class Sedan extends Car {

}

// ... etc. where 10+ classes will extend Car
```

Ex. 2:

```
class Car {

    public enum CarId {
    SEDAN,
    COUPE,
    // ...
    }

    public Car(CarId id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Assume in this case that Sedan, Coupe, etc. won't be providing much more complexity (perhaps a single field that may or may not be null; that is, a field that some will use, but others won't).

In what situation are each of these used?  What specific characteristics of a problem would that determine which to use? **Specifically, why would you use the second one instead of the first.**  I fail to see how that's so vague it warrants a down vote.  The question doesn't ask what inheritance is or what enums are.  Provide a reason for a down vote.

Fails to show research effort:
This is very specific, the only reason I'm asking is because I can't google the example.  If this is the reason, at least provide an information source.

Vague:
It's very specific.

Useful:
I'm faced with a situation that could use both.  I could *use* some information on what I should look for to decide.

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: @var___ edited. I think Downvotes without explanation deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this way :

Car is an object. In OOP, Object has state( also called properties/attributes), behavior.

Object state is represented using class fields and object behavior is represented using methods.

Now, with your example: Car is an object, car's properties are name, brand, ...etc. Car's behavior will be applyBrakse(), accelarate(), ... etc.

So I would create Car object as below :

```
class Car {

    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String type;
    // ...... other properties

    // constructor, getter and setter methods

    public void applyBrakes() {
        // code to apply brakes
    }

    public void accelarate() {
        // code to apply brakes
    }

    // ... other behavioral methods

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What comes to mind is things like events: AWTEvents is a superclass to  ActionEvent, AdjustmentEvent, etc. These subclasses, in the above model, could also simply be a property of an AWTEvent.  Instead they have extended AWTEvent with an event ID.  Why did they choose to do this instead of simply being a property of an AWTEvent?

Comment: @roundar : If you want to have inheritance then you can have `class Vehicle` and your `class Car extends Vehicle`.

Comment: What then makes us decide to have Car be a subclass of Vehicle instead of a property?

Comment: Read about Generalization in OOP, Read about `is-a`, `has-a` relationships.

Comment: **That** is the wording I needed to look into on my own, thanks a lot.